# Check table overlap with JavaScript & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I'm developing timetable web app and I have some problem with it. When I click the button clicked row data will go to under table which I set 'selected subject' table.

And I want to make it if the subject code are already in selected subject, alert the message and prevent put data in to second table.

At first time I thought When I click the add button, make a array and put the subject Code data, and every time when I click the add button, check the array if the subject code are already in there or not.

And Here's my code.

```
// Add Subject Button Click Event
$('.checkBtn').click(function () {
    let checkBtn = $(this);

    let tr = checkBtn.parent().parent();
    let td = tr.children();

    let table = document.getElementById('subjectSelectBody');
    let row = table.insertRow();

    let subjectCode = row.insertCell(0);
    let subjectName = row.insertCell(1);
    let credit = row.insertCell(2);
    let major = row.insertCell(3);
    let day = row.insertCell(4);
    let time = row.insertCell(5);
    let deleteButton = row.insertCell(6);

    // Get Select Tag data
    let subject = td.eq(0).text();
    let x = document.getElementById(subject).value;


    // put data into second table (selected table)
    subjectCode.innerHTML = td.eq(0).text();
    subjectName.innerHTML = td.eq(1).text();
    credit.innerHTML = Number(td.eq(2).text());
    major.innerHTML = td.eq(3).text();
    day.innerHTML = x;
    time.innerHTML = td.eq(5).text();
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "<button>delete</button>";

    // When clicks delete button, remove the data from second table
    $('button').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
    });

    // Create subject add Array to check overlap
    let sbjCodeArr=new Array();
    sbjCodeArr.push(td.eq(0).text());
    console.log(sbjCodeArr);

    // Total Array to deliver to server
    let tdArr = [td.eq(0).text(), td.eq(1).text(), Number(td.eq(2).text()), td.eq(3).text(), x, td.eq(5).text()];
    console.log(tdArr);
})
```

[image: Main]

Comment: can you provide code snipate what is problem exactly are you facing.

Comment: can you provide me your code or put your code in jsfiddel and shere link here i can't understand and i can't resolve this.